Lighthouse Reports Showing Mobile Layout Despite Desktop Configuration File
Lighthouse by defaults to the mobile layout. I am passing the lighthouseDesktopConfig file, located at lighthouse/core/config/lr-desktop-config from the node_modules to configure the tests for the desktop layout. However, the reports are still reflecting the mobile layout. Even with the desktop configuration being passed and there is also an error saying test timeout of 30000ms exceeded when i try running the test cases.
The version's installed are
"playwright-lighthouse": "^3.2.6",
 "lighthouse": "^10.4.0"

.
import {test } from '@playwright/test';
import{
    SLOW_3G_CONFIG
} from './constants.js'
import { checkWebVitals } from './webVitalsUtils.js';
import lighthouseDesktopConfig from 'lighthouse/core/config/lr-desktop-config.js';
import lighthouseMobileConfig from  'lighthouse/core/config/lr-mobile-config.js';

test('Performance metrics for Slow 3g network',async({playwright,browserName})=>{
    test.skip(browserName !== 'chromium','Running only on chrome');
    const browser=await playwright.chromium.launch({
        args:['--remote-debugging-port=9223'],
    });
    

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(HOME_PAGE_URL,{waitUntil:'networkidle'});

    await checkWebVitals({
        lighthouseConfig:lighthouseDesktopConfig,
        lightHouseNetworkOpts:SLOW_3G_CONFIG,
        portNumber:9223,
        page:page,
        reportName: 'lh-report-slow-3g-desktop',
    });
});


According to the playwright docs you need to emulate the device you want to use. Playwright has a built in helper for this in @playwright/test. You can add the following to your config for every device you want to test
playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test'; // import devices

export default defineConfig({
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Mobile Safari',
      use: {
        ...devices['iPhone 13'],
      },
    },
  ],
});

Alternatively, you can directly set the viewport in your tests:
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test.use({
  viewport: { width: 1600, height: 1200 },
});

test('my test', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});


I tried the solution mentioned above, but I'm still getting the same result. The Lighthouse report is showing the mobile view for a desktop configuration, as shown in the image attached to the question.
